# how to create a search filter in php?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first time to create a search filter. I had "switch statement" in mind. Whatever keywords the user inputs, it should check in switch statement. That switch statement will check values if it is present in mysql database. If it exists then it will display information in a table. If not, then it will redirect to "NoResultsFound.html". So far, this is what I have in mind. Am I correct? If not, what should I modify?

Comment: You can't guess user inputs to  have them in a switch!
You have to take user input and run a LIKE '%userinput%'  query to see if you get results.

Comment: please explain.. is '".$userinput."' the same as %userinput% ?

Comment: Guess that you have a POST form for user input keyword.
<form method="post">
 <input name="keyword" value="type keyword here"/>
 ...
</form>
After submit you take  $keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);
And then you make a query : "select * from `dbname` where field like '%".$keyword."%'";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a word "keyword" has a special meaning and has nothing to do with ArtistName and SongName.

So, start from substring search in all fields.

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
$query  = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ArtistName LIKE '%$search%' OR SongName LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Also note, there is no use in redirecting user anywhere. Just stay on the same page, display entered value in the search string (processed via `htmlspecialchars()`) and let user edit it and make another search

Comment: good solution  but i prefer addslashes or any other php functions that does not required an open database connection to escape the strings

Comment: @eric there cannot be a case when you're going to escape but have no connection yet

Answer (score 4):

Why not accomplish this using SQL?

```
SELECT * FROM wherever WHERE keywords LIKE '%keyword%'
```

This will return rows which match keyword and if it returns an empty recordset you can redirect them to `NoResultsFound.html`.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of putting that query in my switch statement, as I have columns like ArtistName, SongName. so whatever user inputs, it should match with those columns.

Comment: @deepz what's the use of this switch statement?

Comment: switch statement is similar to multiple if.. else if in a block. If first case returns false then it will break to the next case, and so on. But, why are you asking? Is switch statement unsuitable to use in search filter?

Comment: @deepz what's the use of switch statement in your case? what conditions you're going to check? Give an example

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add the search keyword to the query and then check if the query returns any results at all.
I will refer to a simple database connection class (PHP) I've built ([here](http://picselbocs.com/Database.class.php)) because it makes it easier to explain:

```
$keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);
$db = new Database();
$db->connect(DB_NAME,DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);

$query   = "SELECT your_field FROM your_table WHERE target_field LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";
$result = getAssocArray($query);

if (!empty($result)) {   
     // do something if there is at least a match 
}
else {
     // do something if there is not match
}

$db->disconnect();
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @deepz Glad to help out. Hope you find the php class useful too. Cheers!

Comment: yes I did. I learnt a lot from all of you. I appreciate every comments as I take them all very keenly.:)